# Finding permutations for balanced distribution of values in lists

Tags: algorithm, permutation, mathematical-optimization

*Sorry for the bad title, but I don't know how to call this.*

I have K lists, N elements in each, for example:

```
[8, 5, 6]
[4, 3, 2]
[6, 5, 0]
```

and I want to find such a permutation of the lists' elements, so that the sum of elements in first column, second column etc are as close to each other as possible (so the distribution is "fair").

In my example that would be (probably):

```
      [8,  5,  6]
      [4,  2,  3] -- the lists contain the same values
      [0,  6,  5]    just in different order
sums: 12, 13, 14
```

Is there some more elegant way than finding all the permutations for each list, and brute-force finding the "ideal" combination of them?

I'm not asking for code, just give me a hint how to do it, if you know.
Thanks!

ps. the lists can be quite large, and more of them - think ~20x~20 max.

Comment: even though i don't think there is a way will be significantly faster than brute force search, i still find this problem interesting.

Comment: Since the "fair" is not well defined, you could use some randomized algorithm with greedy element picking to generate some solutions and then pick the better one.

Comment: Yeah, but what I really want to find is a distance between highest and lowest column value for the ideal permutation. I'm not sure if random shuffle will be an optimal solution, although it will certainly be easy to implement.

Comment: Okay I tried with random, and it works reasonably well for small "boards", but for larger it is not reliable at all.

Comment: What is the range of an element in an array?

Answer (score 2):

If you can accept an approximation, I would do it iteratively :

- Sort matrix lines by descending weight (sum of line elements).
  *Edit : Sorting first by max element in line could be better.*
- Each time you are going to add a new line to your result matrix, put smaller elements into higher columns.
- Order lines of your result matrix back to their initial state (if you have to).

It works with your example, but will obviously not be always perfect.

Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/slaur/eb1b3b6717bd99bb2d36) (javascript)

Comment: This unfortunately does not seem to work for larger matrices very well, but it's a good idea for a heuristic, certainly better than random shuffle.

Comment: @MightyPork if not done you could try to ask your question at Math Stackexchange or Mathoverflow. At least someone might be able to put a name on your problem